# Error while Converting to Json Object

Tags: android, json

I am working with restful webservice and I get json from it like the following

```
  response = [{"id":1,"name":"Appetizers","image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADgAAAAkCAIAAABT8G6pAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAABb5SURBVFhHPVgHUFPrtmbevTPvvnPvO8eKKJ1ASAikEEIaSYBAEkroSLWBHex67A3FBhYsWEFUBBuCDRRRpCMlhPS+0zs1gHD0HN72vjfvnzV/dpI9s7 ....
```

after that I want to convert this json to JSONObject

```
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
```

and when I execute this command I get the follwoing error

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"resturantID":{"phoneNo":"a","id":1,"fax":"a","address":"a" ...
```

my program was working good when I was using glassfish 3 because the json structure was different from this 
what is the problem ?

Comment: here the "response" string is not JSONObject. It is JSONArray. You first need to get the JSONArray and from that you need to fetch all the JSONObjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `response` hold the output of the stringbuilder after iterations
then you can try below code

```
try{
            jArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            }
}
```

NOTE:do not forget to declare `jArray`(object of JSONARRAY) and `json_data`(object of JSONOBJECT) at class level

Answer (score 1):

This is a `JSONArray` and not a `JSONObject` - to make a JSONObject from it, use

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

this gets the first JSONObject from this JSONArray.

If you have multiple JSONObjects, use this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject;
for(int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length(); n++)
{
    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem is on your JSON. JSON is not valid.

```
"id":1
```

it should be

```
"id":"1"
```

Please check.

Comment: this actually is valid, it´s just an `int` instead of a `String`